# Capture video while playing audio in WP8 or WP81

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Whenever I try to record a video using the CaptureSource it stops whatever audio was playing. How do I prevent recording video from stopping the audio being played?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to capture video with the camera or record your app? Also, please include some example code.

Comment: I want to capture video with the camera but the songs being played gets muted for the period of recording.